# "use_sim_time" parameter disabled tf

Tags: ros, use-sim-time, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,every one,

After I added `<param name ="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>` in my launch file,the rviz can not show the tf tree and there was an error in the RobotModel:`No transform from [base_laser]to[odom]` and a warning in Global Status: `No tf data.Actual error:Fixed Frame [odom] does not exist`.
When I entered `rostopic echo /tf` ,there was a warning :`no messages received and simulated time is active.Is /clock being published?`

So the root cause is the clock message not be published.How can I publish the /clock messages ?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214458/%22use_sim_time%22-parameter-disabled-tf/) by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-24**:
Do you play a bagfile?
Can you please edit your question and add some of the commands you execute?

**Comment by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on 2015-07-25**:
No,I did not play any bagfile.
How can I publish the clock message?
Will the bagfile publish a clock message?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-07-26**:
@redskydeng What were you trying to achieve by setting `use_sim_time`?

**Comment by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on 2015-07-29**:
I am using the *gazebo*.Should I write some codes to publish the /clock topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I'll just give it a go answering now.

You can only use simulation time, if you are either playing a bagfile (then, do `rosbag play mybag.bag --clock`) or when you have a simulation running.
If you are using `gazebo`, this should be set to true for synchronizing `gazebo` with ROS. See [the documentation here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_comm#GazeboPublishedParameters). Usually, you put this parameter in the launch file of you simulator, which you usually start as the first launch file.

Note, that the nodes need to be written using the [ROS Time API](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time) and not using walltime, as this would mean that they are not able to properly use simulation time. See [here for more details](http://wiki.ros.org/Clock#Using_Simulation_Time_from_the_.2BAC8-clock_Topic).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on 2015-07-29**:
mig,

Thanks!
The *rosbag play* publishes **/clock** message when using '--clock' parameter.

Thx for your hint:)